# Apache NiFi on Cloudera Changing variables from Unauthorized Referencing Components to Referencing Processors

Tags: variables, apache-nifi, cloudera-cdp

Goal is to move the processors that are using a variable from "Unauthorized Referencing Components" to "Referencing Processors" I've recently moved from HDP to CFM for Apache NiFi and the variables that are set in my PutHDFS, GetHDFS, and MoveHDFS are referencing variables that are classified as "Unauthorized Referencing Components"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required a changer to policies for restricted components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).